# Вызов метода у нулевого указателя

Tags: c++, неопределённое-поведение

Сегодня состоялся следующий спор с коллегами. Они утверждали, что в таком коде нет никаких проблем, и все будет работать везде одинаково:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S{
    int a;
    void foo(){
        std::cout << "hello";
    }
};

int main(){
    S *p = nullptr;
    p->foo();  //hello
}
```

Мол к данным мы не обращаемся => В память по адресу 0 не лезем => Проблем нет.
Я им с пеной у рта доказывал, что если вызывать любой не статический метод у `nullptr` это сразу неопределенное поведение, и не важно что там в этом методе происходит.

Вопросы:

- Кто прав?
- Где в стандарте об этом написано?
- Есть ли в стандарте что-то о том, как должен быть реализован `this`?

Comment: Работать будет до первого виртуального метода.

Comment: @MrBin, Речь именно про такой код. Без данных и виртуальных методов.

Comment: А вот зачем может хотеться писать такой код? Вот в чем загвоздка. Потому что так может человек? плохо.

Comment: Не совсем то, но вот это `void foo(){ if(this) std::cout << "hello";}` — гарантированный UB с точки зрения `gcc` и `clang`'а

Comment: "Без данных" и "к данным мы не обращаемся" - это несколько разные вещи.

Comment: @KoVadim, речь зашла про то как `this` попадает в метод. И в качестве подтверждения своих слов, человек привел подобный код, и заверте...

Comment: если уж так, то это все на откуп реализации компилятора. Но передавать первым параметром - это простой логичный способ. И вот только в методов в с++ как бы  нет:) и если человек говорил именно "попадает в методы", то можно знатно потроллить.

Comment: Много чего будет работать, если закладываться на конкретную реализацию конкретного компилятора на конкретной платформе. Это не значит, что так нужно делать. И без выкрутасов полно ошибок в программах. :-)

Comment: Сейчас подобная конструкция работает. Но когда-то то же самое говорили и про преобразование указателей между несовместимыми типами (что нарушает strict aliasing rule). Тоже говорили, что не выстрелит. А оно возьми и выстрели, когда разработчики GCC сделали оптимизатор более аггрессивным. Конкретные примеры можно посмотреть в статье «[Про C++ алиасинг, ловкие оптимизации и подлые баги](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114117/)», глава «Про strict aliasing и баги».

Comment: @Arhad, 100 раз уже говорили, что *strict aliasing* это **не про преобразования указателей**, а про то, что указатели на существенно разные типы **указывают на разные адреса памяти**  (еще точнее -- так компилятор имеет право считать для улучшения оптимизации)

Comment: @avp, и в чём противоречие? Указатели разных типов не могут указывать на один и тот же адрес памяти, и именно поэтому нельзя *в частности* преобразовывать между несовместимыми типами указателей (что как раз и даёт один и тот же адрес для двух несовместимых указателей).

Comment: @Arhad, это формальная логика. На самом деле речь идет о генерации кода в котором одновременно есть действия с данными по разным указателям. Если такой указатель один и вы просто скастили его и далее работаете по второму, то абсолютно ничего, относящегося к *aliasing*-у, не происходит

Comment: @avp, это обсуждение похоже на то, о котором я говорил в вопросе. Можно, конечно, закладываться на конкретную реализацию компилятора, и все будет работать на ней. Но в стандарте написано что [обращение через указатель несоответствующего типа = ub](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11). Про два указателя там ничего нет

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, я понимаю, что в данном случае хотят сказать в пункте 8.2 стандарта. По сути, UB в этом месте подразумевает возможные проблемы с несовместимым выравниванием (ну, может быть  еще такая экзотика, как тэги типов в памяти) для существенно разных типов. К описываемому вами случаю и типичной реализации компилятора/линкера/библиотек  это трудно отнести.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В "классическом" С++ (C++98) ситуация однозначная - разыменование нулевого указателя приводит к *неопределенному поведению*. Соответственно вызов нестатического метода объекта через нулевой указатель приводит к *неопределенному поведению*. Не имеет никакого значения, выполняет ли этот метод доступ к членам класса или не выполняет. Такова позиция спецификации языка. С этой точки зрения вы совершенно правы, а аргументы ваших оппонентов на тему "все везде будет работать" - не более чем следствие "уличного образования" из разряда "смотрю в <strike>книгу</strike> ассемблер, вижу фигу".

В то же время уже довольно давно делаются попытки формирования более гибкой/тонкой спецификации в этом вопросе. В частности

[DR#232: Is indirection through a null pointer undefined behavior?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232)

Однако работа в этом направлении перманентно зависла в состоянии drafting с 2005 года. Честно говоря, создается впечатление, что какого-то внятного толкования текста нынешнего стандарта на эту тему никто дать не может, возможно именно потому, что тема до сих пор является "подвешенной".

Как вы сами понимаете, стандарт не будет заводить отдельную спецификацию на именно ваш частный случай. А как только мы переходим к более общему случаю, то сразу возникают такие ситуации, как преобразование указателя `this` при вызове метода в условиях [множественного] наследования.

```
struct A 
{
  int a; 
};

struct B { 
  int b; 

  void foo() 
  {
    // К данным мы не обращаемся
    // Но чему здесь равно `this`???
    if (this == nullptr)
      ; // ???
  }
};

struct C : A, B
{
};

int main()
{
  C *c = nullptr;
  c->foo();
}
```

Не ясно, должен ли компилятор при преобразованиях указателя `this` в процессе вызова метода базового класса придерживаться правила "null преобразовывается в null"? Вот именно из-за таких тонкостей изначально было принято решение запретить вызовы нестатических методов через нулевой указатель. Что же будет (и есть) сейчас и каковы намерения авторов языка - надо ждать и разбираться.

Обратите внимание, кстати, что [8.5.1.2/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#4) требует, чтобы скрытый параметр `this` при вызове метода класса инициализировался при помощи [*explicit type conversion*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast). То есть в вышеприведенном примере с множественным наследованием в вызове `c->foo()` указатель `this` типа `B` должен инициализироваться как `(B *) c`. Такое преобразование работает по правилу null-в-null и результат `(B *) c` тоже будет нулевым указателем. Однако в GCC и Clang `this` внутри `foo` во время вызова будет иметь значение `0x4`. То есть эти компиляторы не выполнили требований 8.5.1.2/4. Это сразу говорит о том, что GCC и Clang по-прежнему трактуют такой вызов как неопределенное поведение.

P.S. При этом в языке С разыменование нулевого указателя строжайше запрещено.

Comment: >> `Вызов нестатического метода объекта через нулевой указатель приводит к неопределенному поведению.` << вот на это ссылочку достоверную бы...

Comment: и еще: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/04/20/null-pointer-dereferencing-causes-undefined-behavior

Comment: Хорошо, что и gcc и clang на  самом деле не проверяют, что указатель нулевой и прекрасно работают с ним (в bare metall)

Comment: @avp, они не поверяют, но предполагают что он не нулевой. `this == nullptr` [просто заменяется на false на O3](https://godbolt.org/g/7tzAXn).

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Это еще одно подтверждение того, что эти компиляторы расценивают вызов через нулевой указатель, как неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 2):

Код

```
struct S{
    int a;
    void foo(){
        std::cout << "hello";
    }
};
```

идентичен такому

```
void foo(s * this){
    std::cout << "hello";
}
```

Таким образом вызов

```
S *p = nullptr;
p->foo();  //hello
```

эквивалентен такому

```
foo(nullptr)
```

Для проверки просто загляните в окно CPU. Оба вызова сгенерируют один и тот же код

```
mov eax, 0
push eax
call foo
```

т.е. пока Вы не обращаетесь к `this` проблем нет вообще. Обращение к `this` произойдет в двух случаях

1. Вы обратитесь к конкретному полю (может даже из другого метода)
2. Вы вызовете виртуальную функцию, и программа полезет читать VMT по нулевым указателям

А в статические функции указатель `this` не передается вообще

Comment: Вот они мне говорили то же самое. Но мне почему-то кажется что согласно [этому](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.mfct.non-static-2) тут UB. Ведь по адресу 0 точно не будет нужного нам объекта.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, у функции уже существует адрес. Ее можно вызвать.Вы же не думаете, что для каждого объекта создаются свои функции?

Comment: Есть ещё 5.2.2 Function call (4) - "If the function is a non-static member function, the this parameter of the function (9.3.2) shall be initialized with a pointer to the object of the call, converted as if by an explicit type  conversion" - то есть, я понимаю, что должен быть валидный указатель

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Не будет. Но Вам и не нужен объект. Любой класс состоит из двух частей. 1. Набор методов, 2 - набор данных. Чтобы их связать в методы и передается `this` - указатель на данные. Собственно все объекты - это обычные указатели на данные. Нет данных - и фиг с ним. Методы от этого никуда не денутся

Comment: @AntonShchyrov то, что вы пишите - это детали реализации конкретных компиляторов. Да, в некоторых случаях разработчики компилятора могут доопределить UB, намеренно или случайно. Но это не дает никаких гарантий относительно других компиляторов или будущих версий компилятора.

Comment: есть один случай, когда можно дергнуть не виртуальную, не статическую функцию, которая формально не обращается к переменным класса -  деструктор - `p->~S();` и тут все может быть

Comment: В общем случае вызов `S *p = nullptr; p->foo();` НЕ эквивалентен вызову `foo(nullptr);`. Вы этом вы можете запросто убедиться (в т.ч. на практике) на моем примере с множественным наследованием: в первом случае указатель `this` перестанет быть нулевым, а во втором - преобразуется по правилу null-в-null. Какая-то "эквивалентность" возможна только на наивно-примитивных примерах, но вопрос-то более общий.

Comment: @KoVadim: Эта ссылка на 5.2.2/4 с упоминанием "as if by an explicit type conversion" довольно интересна. Формально "explicit type conversion" должно работать по правилу null-в-null. Однако если запустить мой пример с множественным наследованием в GCC или Clang, то внутри моего `foo()` указатель `this` будет равен `0x4`. То есть "explicit type conversion" не произошло. Это возможно только в том случае, если и GCC/Clang видят здесь *неопределенное поведение*.

Comment: (Кстати, 5.2.2/4 в новой нумерации - это 8.5.1.2/4)